# Using Criteria get child class in unidirectional OneToMany relationship in hibernate with JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria

I have two entity class Employee and ContactDetail and Employee class has one to many relationship unidirectional with Jointable annotation. My question is that is it possible to get all contact list from a particular Employee ? Here is my code you can easily understand

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_employee")
    public class Employee implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3919524684485334176L;

        /** The id. */
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        /** The contact details. */
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "tbl_employee_contact", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
        private List<ContactDetail> contactDetails;

        /** The company. */
        @Column
        private String company;

        /** The website. */
        @Column
        private String website;


@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_contact")
public class ContactDetail implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3022172440588672233L;

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "contact_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    /** The type. */
    @Column
    private String type;

    /** The detail. */
    @Column
    private String detail;

    /** The description. */
    @Column
    private String description;

    /** The preferred. */
    @Column
    private boolean preferred;
```

and I fetch contact details lazy so I have to make another method in dao layer so I can get  all contacts from a particular employee. I want something like that

```
public List<ContactDetail> getContactList(string employeeId) {
        final Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(ContactDetail.class, "contact");
        //here some code 
        return contactList;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get contact list directly from Employee instance.

Once you get an Employee instance by doing session.load or anything else, you can just do

```
List<ContactDetail> lContactDetails = employee.getContactDetails()
```

You don't need criteria for doing this.

Comment: Jiteh I load this list Lazy so first time it will not loaded in employee instance.

Comment: Lazy loading does not mean that. Lazy loading means it will be loaded when you call getContactDetails() method. SO calling getContactDetails will fire SQL query if you have specified LAZY loading. It will not hurt to read about LAZY functionality when you get time.

Comment: I read it but its not what are you telling . My question is how can I fetch this list from Criteria .

Comment: I use dozer to map my entity Employee.class to dto Employee.class and I used Dto classes to client class .Jitesh you are right but my use case is different.